# How to compare the String in the scripts of Gatling

Tags: performance, scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

How to compare the String in the scripts of Gatling?
While use code

.check("${loginStatus}".is("1")) to compare the variable loginStatus

It encountered the error that "is" only used for Integer not String member.

Comment: `"${loginStatus}".as[Int].is(1)` maybe?

Comment: It has been resolved, just check the css and not need to saveAs a variable, e.g.   .check(css(xxx)).is("1")